# JDBC DB2 can not connect (SQLSTATE=08S01)

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, db2

I want to connect both Oracle and DB2 databases for some reason using JDBC. In main class when I try to connect Oracle,  Connection is successfull but DB2 connection is NOT successfull giving this error: "Yuva acilirken hata olustu" means "Socket can not be opened" . What can be the problem??? Oracle works but DB2 does not work. I checked all password, usernames, host names and ports again and again for DB2.

```
COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.DB2Exception: [IBM][JDBC Driver] CLI0616E  Yuva açılırken hata oluştu. SQLSTATE=08S01
at COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.net.SQLExceptionGenerator.socketException(Unknown Source)
at COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.net.DB2Connection.create(Unknown Source)
at COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.net.DB2Connection.<init>(Unknown Source)
at COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.net.DB2Driver.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:590)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:232)
```

To get connection, I write these in main,

```
connORA = DirectConnection.getOracleConnection();
connDB2 = DirectConnection.getDB2Connection();
```

My Connection Class I defined Oracle COnnection and DB2 connection as follows: (Maybe there is a problem in DB2 Connection Method? Oracle connects succesfully)

```
  public static Connection getOracleConnection() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
  return getConnection("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@host:port:name", "username", "password");}

  public static Connection getDB2Connection() throws SQLException{
  return getConnection("COM.ibm.db2.jdbc.net.DB2Driver", "jdbc:db2://host:port:name","username", "password");}
```

Comment: So, can you *telnet* to the db2 server host/port ? If you can't, then it's not listening

Comment: Hi Brian, I can not connect DB2 with telnet as you said. But when I telnet Oracle "which I can connect successfully" it does not listen too. Maybe this is not the source of the problem.

Comment: Try to disable firewall on your machine and connect (DB not listening, or the firewall blocking are common reasons for such problems...)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, as @ThePhantom05 mentioned, you should be using the JCC driver, not the older net driver. The correct URL pattern for a DB2 JDBC connection will be   `jdbc:db2://host:port/database_name`

Answer (score 0):

Try using this as your driver instead:

String driver = "com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver";

Comment: please add it as a comment or give more explain instead.